# SQL - Complex Stored Procedure need to change value of 'case when' from integer to VarChar after being counted

Tags: sql

I have a website for an NFL Pool. I'm able to display User Picks and the amount of Wins user has. As of now my CASE WHEN is using integer as win or lost. I would like to change it to be where 1 = 'Won' and 0 = 'Lost' but still count the amount of wins the user has.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help.

My code:

```
DECLARE @commondata TABLE (FullName VARCHAR(30), Game_1 VARCHAR(30), Game_2 VARCHAR(30), Game_3 VARCHAR(30), Game_4 VARCHAR(30), Game_5 VARCHAR(30),
    GameResults_1 INT, GameResults_2 INT, GameResults_3 INT, GameResults_4 INT, GameResults_5 INT)

INSERT INTO @commondata (FullName, Game_1, Game_2, Game_3, Game_4, Game_5, 
                        GameResults_1, GameResults_2 , GameResults_3, GameResults_4, GameResults_5)

SELECT UserPicks.FullName, UserPicks.Game_1, UserPicks.Game_2, UserPicks.Game_3, UserPicks.Game_4, UserPicks.Game_5,
       (CASE WHEN UserPicks.Game_1 = WeeklyResults.GameResults_1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GameResult_1,
       (CASE WHEN UserPicks.Game_2 = WeeklyResults.GameResults_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GameResult_2,
       (CASE WHEN UserPicks.Game_3 = WeeklyResults.GameResults_3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GameResult_3,
       (CASE WHEN UserPicks.Game_4 = WeeklyResults.GameResults_4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GameResult_4,
       (CASE WHEN UserPicks.Game_5 = WeeklyResults.GameResults_5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GameResult_5


 FROM UserPicks
 JOIN WeeklyResults ON UserPicks.Week = WeeklyResults.Week
 WHERE WeeklyResults.Week = 'Week1'

 -- Unpivot the table.  
(SELECT FullName, Game_1, Game_2, Game_3, Game_4, Game_5, SUM(Points) As Total
 FROM 
(SELECT *
   FROM @commondata) pvt 
UNPIVOT  
   (Points FOR Game IN   
      (GameResults_1, GameResults_2, GameResults_3, GameResults_4, GameResults_5)
)AS Total 
GROUP BY FullName, Game_1, Game_2, Game_3, Game_4, Game_5)
```

Comment: Yes. It's possible. You can use case inside the sum.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still new at this and I've been doing a lot of trial an error. Could you please show me a little code possibly mine of what you're saying

Comment: Do you want to change the data type in the table or doesn't that matter as long as it reads 'Won' (or 'Lost') in the final output?

Comment: In the final output. Just need to display it on my site

Comment: some expected output might help.

Comment: I wanted to try your code, but in the final output, there are no 0s or 1s but the results of the games and the number of wins of the user. Is that my misconception, that I expected to see the win/loss of the user for every game or is there something missing in your posted code? Please also provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements along with some sample data, that would make it easier to do the "right thing".

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I took the liberty to reformat, remove redundant lines and use table acronyms to make it easier to read/understand:

```
DECLARE @commondata TABLE (FullName VARCHAR(30)
    , Game_1 VARCHAR(30)
    , Game_2 VARCHAR(30)
    , Game_3 VARCHAR(30
    , Game_4 VARCHAR(30)
    , Game_5 VARCHAR(30)
    , GameResults_1 VARCHAR(4)
    , GameResults_2 VARCHAR(4)
    , GameResults_3 VARCHAR(4)
    , GameResults_4 VARCHAR(4)
    , GameResults_5 VARCHAR(4));

INSERT INTO @commondata
SELECT UP.FullName
    , UP.Game_1
    , UP.Game_2
    , UP.Game_3
    , UP.Game_4
    , UP.Game_5
    , IIF(UP.Game_1 = WR.GameResults_1, 'Won', 'Lost') AS GameResult_1
    , IIF(UP.Game_2 = WR.GameResults_2, 'Won', 'Lost') AS GameResult_2
    , IIF(UP.Game_3 = WR.GameResults_3, 'Won', 'Lost') AS GameResult_3
    , IIF(UP.Game_4 = WR.GameResults_4, 'Won', 'Lost') AS GameResult_4
    , IIF(UP.Game_5 = WR.GameResults_5, 'Won', 'Lost') AS GameResult_5
 FROM UserPicks UP
 JOIN WeeklyResults WR ON UP.Week = WR.Week
 WHERE WR.Week = 'Week1';

 -- Unpivot the table.  
SELECT FullName
    , Game_1
    , Game_2
    , Game_3
    , Game_4
    , Game_5
    , SUM(IIF(Result='Won', 1, 0)) As Total
FROM @commondata 
UNPIVOT (
    Result FOR Game IN (GameResults_1
        , GameResults_2
        , GameResults_3
        , GameResults_4
        , GameResults_5)
    ) AS Total 
GROUP BY FullName
    , Game_1
    , Game_2
    , Game_3
    , Game_4
    , Game_5;
```